# How I can read headers of Bc in Multichain

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, blockchain.info-api

How I can read headers of Bc in Multichain? I'm using Multichain Json-Rpc API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MultiChain, miners must prove their identity when creating a block. We can use a recent feature known as streams in MultiChain to read the timestamp, which is taken from the header of the block in which the item is confirmed. Each blockchain has an optional ‘root’ stream, which is defined in its parameters and exists from the moment the chain is created. This enables a blockchain to be used immediately for storing and retrieving data, without waiting for a stream to be explicitly created. Refer to the following article for more details.

[enter link description here](https://www.multichain.com/blog/2016/09/introducing-multichain-streams/)